# Responsive buttons SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, button, flexbox, sapui5, responsive

I wanted to know if there is a way for these buttons to adapt when I am with a mobile device. That is to say, right now the three buttons are horizontal, but when the device is smaller instead of adapting and becoming vertical they go out of the screen, would there be a solution for this?

```
<FlexBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center">
    <items>
        <Button type="Accept" class="button" press="onSubmit1" text="1" width="100%"/>
        <Button type="Accept" class="button" press="onSubmit2" text="2" width="100%"/>
        <Button type="Accept" class="button" press="onSubmit3" text="3" width="100%"/>
    </items>
</FlexBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

the solution was quite simple, I publish it in case someone clueless does not know like me, is adding the `wrap` property, this makes that instead of overflowing the information, is placed in several lines

```
<FlexBox alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center" wrap="Wrap">
```